# FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion in mxd - don't want to add new layer to mxd

Tags: arcgis, arcpy, arcmap

I am running a script from the Python window in ArcMap.

```
listOfLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)
fileGeodb = r"C:\foo\bar\gdb_name.gdb"

for layer in listOfLayers:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(layer, fileGeodb, layer.name)
```

This exports each layer to the geodatabase, but also adds it to the mxd. How can I avoid adding it to the mxd?

ETA I've read the documentation here but adding to the mxd (or not) is not one of the options in the parameters.
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm

Comment: Be aware - that documentation is for ArcGIS Pro when you are using ArcMap. It's not always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ArcMap, you can uncheck this option in the Geoprocessing Options: Geprocessing menu > Geoprocessing Options > Uncheck "Add results of geoprocessing operations to the display".

[image]

You can also use the [env.addOutputsToMap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/env.htm) property:

```
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = 0
listOfLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)
fileGeodb = r"C:\foo\bar\gdb_name.gdb"

for layer in listOfLayers:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(layer, fileGeodb, layer.name)
```

Comment: thank you, but I would like to do it within the script if possible.